# Facebook like button not working in android app

Tags: android, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

There is a Facebook like button in my android app. But when clicking on that I got this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'activity' cannot be null
                  at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:36)
                  at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.<init>(FacebookDialogBase.java:53)
                  at com.facebook.share.internal.LikeDialog.<init>(LikeDialog.java:67)
                  at com.facebook.share.internal.LikeActionController.presentLikeDialog(LikeActionController.java:824)
                  at com.facebook.share.internal.LikeActionController.toggleLike(LikeActionController.java:698)
                  at com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView.toggleLike(LikeView.java:569)
                  at com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView.access$300(LikeView.java:52)
                  at com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView$1.onClick(LikeView.java:519)
                  at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase$1.onClick(FacebookButtonBase.java:312)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code for Facebook like button

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeView);
likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);      
likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
    "http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-
     launchmode/en",
      LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH)
```

This is code for like button in xml file.

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
                android:id="@+id/likeView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

How can I solve it

Comment: are you using any object with name "activity"?

Comment: Have you added this on Manifest   `<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />`

Comment: @Naz141 yes I added that

Comment: @play_err_ No I did'nt used any object with that name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
btnLike = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.btnLike);
btnLike.setObjectIdAndType("https://www.facebook.com/androidlift", LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
"http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-
 launchmode/en",
  LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH)
```

with

```
likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
"http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-
 launchmode/en",
  LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE
```

)